# Why does shallow rendering work and testing library render does not with final form component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-testing-library, react-final-form

Currently I have a react component that returns a Form from react-final-form. I am trying to write a test suite for the component using testing-library instead of enzyme. When I shallow render the component with enzyme it works fine but I really want to be using testing-library and when I utilize render I get the following error. The only way I have been able to avoid the error is by specifying a wrapper in the render options as a 2nd param but then I'm just not getting anything rendered related to my component.

```sh
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined

      23 | 
      24 |   it('takes onSuccess, showHeadlines, and initSignUpForm props', () => {
    > 25 |     const wrapper = render(<SignUpSignInForm {...props} />)
         |                     ^
      26 | 
      27 |     // console.log(wrapper.getByTestId('auth-forms'))
      28 |   })
```

This is the stack trace:

```sh
Error: Uncaught [TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined]
          at reportException (/Users/glamsquad/Documents/GLAMSQUAD/phoenix/glamsquad/node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/helpers/runtime-script-errors.js:66:24)
          at invokeEventListeners (/Users/glamsquad/Documents/GLAMSQUAD/phoenix/glamsquad/node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:209:9)
          at HTMLUnknownElementImpl._dispatch (/Users/glamsquad/Documents/GLAMSQUAD/phoenix/glamsquad/node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:119:9)
          at HTMLUnknownElementImpl.dispatchEvent (/Users/glamsquad/Documents/GLAMSQUAD/phoenix/glamsquad/node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:82:17)
          at HTMLUnknownElementImpl.dispatchEvent (/Users/glamsquad/Documents/GLAMSQUAD/phoenix/glamsquad/node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/nodes/HTMLElement-impl.js:30:27)
          at HTMLUnknownElement.dispatchEvent (/Users/glamsquad/Documents/GLAMSQUAD/phoenix/glamsquad/node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/EventTarget.js:157:21)
          at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (/Users/glamsquad/Documents/GLAMSQUAD/phoenix/glamsquad/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:411:16)
          at invokeGuardedCallback (/Users/glamsquad/Documents/GLAMSQUAD/phoenix/glamsquad/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:466:31)
          at commitRootImpl (/Users/glamsquad/Documents/GLAMSQUAD/phoenix/glamsquad/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:25024:9)
          at unstable_runWithPriority (/Users/glamsquad/Documents/GLAMSQUAD/phoenix/glamsquad/node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:815:12) TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined
          at /Users/glamsquad/Documents/GLAMSQUAD/phoenix/glamsquad/node_modules/react-facebook-login/dist/facebook-login-render-props.js:1:5054
          at t.value (/Users/glamsquad/Documents/GLAMSQUAD/phoenix/glamsquad/node_modules/react-facebook-login/dist/facebook-login-render-props.js:1:5084)
          at t.value (/Users/glamsquad/Documents/GLAMSQUAD/phoenix/glamsquad/node_modules/react-facebook-login/dist/facebook-login-render-props.js:1:3822)
          at commitLifeCycles (/Users/glamsquad/Documents/GLAMSQUAD/phoenix/glamsquad/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21964:22)
          at commitLayoutEffects (/Users/glamsquad/Documents/GLAMSQUAD/phoenix/glamsquad/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:25288:7)
          at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (/Users/glamsquad/Documents/GLAMSQUAD/phoenix/glamsquad/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:362:14)
          at invokeEventListeners (/Users/glamsquad/Documents/GLAMSQUAD/phoenix/glamsquad/node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:193:27)
          at HTMLUnknownElementImpl._dispatch (/Users/glamsquad/Documents/GLAMSQUAD/phoenix/glamsquad/node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:119:9)
          at HTMLUnknownElementImpl.dispatchEvent (/Users/glamsquad/Documents/GLAMSQUAD/phoenix/glamsquad/node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:82:17)
          at HTMLUnknownElementImpl.dispatchEvent (/Users/glamsquad/Documents/GLAMSQUAD/phoenix/glamsquad/node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/nodes/HTMLElement-impl.js:30:27)
          at HTMLUnknownElement.dispatchEvent (/Users/glamsquad/Documents/GLAMSQUAD/phoenix/glamsquad/node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/EventTarget.js:157:21)
          at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (/Users/glamsquad/Documents/GLAMSQUAD/phoenix/glamsquad/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:411:16)
          at invokeGuardedCallback (/Users/glamsquad/Documents/GLAMSQUAD/phoenix/glamsquad/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:466:31)
          at commitRootImpl (/Users/glamsquad/Documents/GLAMSQUAD/phoenix/glamsquad/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:25024:9)
          at unstable_runWithPriority (/Users/glamsquad/Documents/GLAMSQUAD/phoenix/glamsquad/node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:815:12)
          at runWithPriority$2 (/Users/glamsquad/Documents/GLAMSQUAD/phoenix/glamsquad/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:12188:10)
          at commitRoot (/Users/glamsquad/Documents/GLAMSQUAD/phoenix/glamsquad/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24865:3)
          at finishSyncRender (/Users/glamsquad/Documents/GLAMSQUAD/phoenix/glamsquad/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24251:5)
          at performSyncWorkOnRoot (/Users/glamsquad/Documents/GLAMSQUAD/phoenix/glamsquad/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24223:9)
          at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (/Users/glamsquad/Documents/GLAMSQUAD/phoenix/glamsquad/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:23590:7)
          at scheduleRootUpdate (/Users/glamsquad/Documents/GLAMSQUAD/phoenix/glamsquad/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26945:3)
          at updateContainerAtExpirationTime (/Users/glamsquad/Documents/GLAMSQUAD/phoenix/glamsquad/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26973:10)
          at updateContainer (/Users/glamsquad/Documents/GLAMSQUAD/phoenix/glamsquad/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:27075:10)
          at /Users/glamsquad/Documents/GLAMSQUAD/phoenix/glamsquad/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:27663:7
          at unbatchedUpdates (/Users/glamsquad/Documents/GLAMSQUAD/phoenix/glamsquad/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24375:12)
          at legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer (/Users/glamsquad/Documents/GLAMSQUAD/phoenix/glamsquad/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:27662:5)
          at Object.render (/Users/glamsquad/Documents/GLAMSQUAD/phoenix/glamsquad/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:27756:12)
          at /Users/glamsquad/Documents/GLAMSQUAD/phoenix/glamsquad/node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/pure.js:101:25
          at batchedUpdates$1 (/Users/glamsquad/Documents/GLAMSQUAD/phoenix/glamsquad/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24328:12)
          at act (/Users/glamsquad/Documents/GLAMSQUAD/phoenix/glamsquad/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-test-utils.development.js:1120:14)
          at render (/Users/glamsquad/Documents/GLAMSQUAD/phoenix/glamsquad/node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/pure.js:97:26)
          at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/glamsquad/Documents/GLAMSQUAD/phoenix/glamsquad/src/sign-form/index.test.js:25:21)
          at Object.asyncJestTest (/Users/glamsquad/Documents/GLAMSQUAD/phoenix/glamsquad/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmineAsyncInstall.js:102:37)
          at /Users/glamsquad/Documents/GLAMSQUAD/phoenix/glamsquad/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:43:12
          at new Promise (<anonymous>)
          at mapper (/Users/glamsquad/Documents/GLAMSQUAD/phoenix/glamsquad/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:26:19)
          at /Users/glamsquad/Documents/GLAMSQUAD/phoenix/glamsquad/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:73:41
          at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    console.error node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21704
      The above error occurred in the <t> component:
          in t (at sign-form/index.js:293)
          in form (at sign-form/index.js:197)
          in section (created by Context.Consumer)
          in Styled(section) (at sign-form/index.js:196)
          in ReactFinalForm (at sign-form/index.js:115)
          in SignUpSignInForm (at sign-form/index.test.js:25)
```

The component simplified:

```js
const SignUpSignInForm = ({
  history,
  location,
  onSuccess,
  showHeadlines = false,
  initSignUpForm = true
}) => {
  const [formModeSignUp, toggleFormModeSignUp] = useBooleanState(initSignUpForm)
  const [termsAccepted, toggleTermsAccepted] = useBooleanState()
  const [rememberAuth, toggleRememberAuth] = useBooleanState(false)
  const [passwordResetModal, togglePasswordResetModal] = useBooleanState(false)
  const [working, setWorking] = useState(false)

  const doSubmit = async ({ email, password, nameFirst, nameLast, phone }) => {
    if (formModeSignUp) {
      // sign up
      await signUp(email, nameFirst, nameLast, phone, password)
    } else {
      // sign in
      await signInWeb(email, password, rememberAuth)
    }

    if (onSuccessRedirectUrl) {
      history.push(onSuccessRedirectUrl)
    } else {
      return onSuccess()
    }
  }

  // calls provided onSubmit function catching any errors and returning as form errors for display
  const onSubmitWithErrorHandling = async values => {
    setWorking(true)
    try {
      await doSubmit(values)
      setWorking(false)
    } catch (error) {
      setWorking(false)
      return { [FORM_ERROR]: error }
    }
  }

  return (
    <Form
      onSubmit={onSubmitWithErrorHandling}
      data-testid="auth-forms"
      render={props => {
        const {
          handleSubmit,
          submitting,
          pristine,
          invalid,
          submitError,
          hasValidationErrors,
          dirtySinceLastSubmit
        } = props

        const submitDisabled =
          submitting ||
          pristine ||
          hasValidationErrors ||
          (invalid && !dirtySinceLastSubmit) ||
          (formModeSignUp && !termsAccepted)

        return (
            <SignUpSection>
              <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} noValidate>
                {// form inputs here....}
              </form>
            </SignUpSection>
          </>
        )
      }}
    />
  )
}

SignUpSignInForm.propTypes = {
  onSuccess: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default SignUpSignInForm
```